# Is There a Ready Made Plotting/Charting/Graphing Server?

Tags: plot, flot

I'm gonna be starting work on an analytics portal for a website soon, and wanted a little web app that I could send data points and graphing details (or have it pull these from some database) and have it use some charting technology like flot, or google chart tools to generate graphs based on that information. I was going to build my own, but before I started, I wanted to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel. This does seem like an obvious use for a graphing framework like flot, so, does anyone know if something like this already exists?

Comment: yes this is re-inventing the wheel, what serverside language do you intend on using (eg. php, java) so we can suggest a solution

Comment: I'd prefer to use Python, but since I'm building from scratch for the explicit purpose of making a portal for accessing charts, I'm open to other languages if they have a better framework for this.